# Infinite Linear Combination of symmetric Random Variables

Tags: probability-theory, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Let $(Y_n)$ be i.i.d. random variables taking values $1$ and $-1$ with equal probabilities. I want to compute the function
$$
f(x) = \mathbb{P}[\sum_n x_nY_n \text{ converges}]
$$
defined on sequences $x = (x_n)$ of real numbers.

---

**Trials:**

I am stuck at a early stage. Writing
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}[\sum_n x_n Y_n \text{ converges}] &= 1 - \mathbb{P}[\sum_n x_nY_n\text{ does not converge}],
\end{align*}
I am trying to show $\mathbb{P}[\sum_n x_n Y_n\text{ does not converge}] = \frac{1}{2}$ if $x_n \not= 0$ and $ = 1$ otherwise. If $x_n = 0$, then obviously the sum converges. If $x_n \not= 0$, then I am trying to use Borel-Cantelli to get some kind of result, but hasn't been making much progress. Am I going in the wrong way here?

Comment: You want [Kolmogrov's three series theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_three-series_theorem), which should give you a complete characterization of $f(x)$. Another handy theorem is the [Kolmogorov's zero-one law](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_zero%E2%80%93one_law), which should give you an indication that $f(x)$ can only ever equal $0$ or $1$.

Comment: $f(x)=1$ if $\sum x_n^{2} <\infty$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: @C-RAM I actually never learned these two theorems... From what I have seen, there are certain sufficient conditions needed to be added so that the conditions in Kolmogrov's theorem is satisfied? Those certain sufficient conditions are related to the zero-one law?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean... In any case, the three series theorem is the important bit here; you can ignore the zero-one law (I mostly mentioned it to give extra context about why this specific type of problem ends up having a somewhat boring binary answer).  The comment by geetha290krm should be correct; simply check that the conditions for the three series theorem (as written in the Wiki page) applied to the sequence of random variables $X_n=x_nY_n$ are satisfied if and only if $\sum_n x_n^2$ converges.